# Why do some binary files have null bytes between characters when storing strings?

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding, binaryfiles

Back when I used to mess around with .CON files (the native file format that games would use on the Xbox 360) I remember seeing the text in those files separated by null bytes when viewing them with a hex editor.

Today I've also noticed that while looking at a localstorage file from Chrome with an SQLite browser; all the text fields stored as binary/blob values like this:

```
22007700730073003a002f002f006700
6100740065007700610079002e006400
6900730063006f00720064002e006700
67002200
```

What's with the null bytes? Is this a different type of character encoding? I figure it can't be utf8 since utf8 wouldn't use two bytes to encode characters in the ascii range, but maybe I'm wrong?

Comment: There's UTF-16LE too!

Comment: I hope you can see from the answers that the zero bytes are _part_ of a character, not _between_ the characters.

Comment: @TomBlodget yes I was sure of that, especially since the last byte was also null, I mainly wasn’t sure which character encoding was being used as I wasn’t familiar with that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's UTF-16 for `"wss://gateway.discord.gg"`. (If you see alternating ASCII bytes and null bytes, you can bet that it's UTF-16.)

Since a JavaScript string is UTF-16, and SQLite supports storing text in UTF-16, it's not surprising that Chrome would use this for its implementation of localstorage.

Comment: Ahh that makes total sense, exactly what I was looking to know, thank you!

Comment: @BrianLeishman: Since you have an SQLite database browser, you can confirm this by running the command `PRAGMA ENCODING`.

Comment: @dan04 actually running that gives me UTF-8?

Comment: If it's being stored as a BLOB, then it's not affected by the database's encoding.

Comment: @JoshLee that's what I figured

Answer (score 2):

That is probably UTF-16 encoding, which uses two bytes to store ASCII characters and is the preferred unicode encoding for most windows function calls.